# "Community Bulleting Board" went away?

Tags: discussion, site-content

Did I miss a memo? :) Did the "Community Bulleting Board" feature -- the colored block that used to show things we[moderators] tagged with a certain tag -- go away? We used to have the "asking questions" meta Q/A tacked up there... but now I can't even find the tag that we used to use.

o.O

**update**

...it's the "featured" tag which I found in the tag list. I've applied it to the 'how to ask' meta Q, will see if it makes the Comm. Bulletin Board reappear on the main site.